# Liberar memoria RAM en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un bucle infinito que realiza una serie de operaciones con distintos tipos de archivos, lee archivos, crea diferentes xml e inserta en una base de datos. Para ello utilizo el siguiente código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          Thread_WKAS  miRunnable = new Thread_WKAS();
          Thread hilo1= new Thread(miRunnable);

         hilo1.start();
    } 
    private static class Thread_WKAS implements Runnable{
      public void run() {
         while (true){

          leer_archivos_crear_archivos_insertar_registros();

          System.gc();
          System.runFinalization();
          System.gc();
         }
      }
   }
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando lleva varios días trabajando la memoría RAM se llena hasta los 1024 MB que le he indicado con VM Options -Xms 1024m.
Lo que me indica que el recolector de basura no elimina las referencias de las variables, he leído que poniendo las variables usadas a null el garballe colector eliminaría las referencias muertas, pero tengo un montón de variables internas. ¿Mi pregunta es si existe una opción diferente para que no aumente el tamaño de la memoria usada en la aplicación?

Comment: Pero agrega el código del método `leer_archivos_crear_archivos_insertar_registros()`, que ahí es donde debe estar el problema.

Comment: E. Betanzos el código de ese método es muy extenso incluyendo diferentes clases.

Comment: Pero es que lo que puedas estar haciendo bien o mal debe estar ahí. Porque el modo en que ejecutas el hilo es correcto.

Comment: Lo que ha propuesto Pablo Lozano como respuesta es el problema, utilizar variables de clase con static, pero esas variables las utilizo en diferentes métodos, las cargo en un método que luego utilizo en otros, he puesto el código principal pensando en una solución desde el hilo principal. Ya que es imposible poner todo el código, tengo nueve clases diferentes y una infinidad de métodos en cada una.

Comment: Entonces revisa cuales de esas variables son imprescindibles  y evita crear tantos objetos como puedas. Con más hilos solo vas a conseguir, en teoría, que las tareas se ejecuten más rápido pero el tema de la memoria no tiene nada que ver con los hilos que utilizas.

Comment: Son diferentes objetos los que utilizo que cuando termino de utilizarlos hago un: datos_archivo1.clear(); pensando que ese espacio de memoria utilizada la liberaría tras un tiempo, luego en la siguiente vuelta vuelvo a utilizar el objeto con un datos_archivo1.add(lo que sea);

Comment: Si haces un clear, efectivamente debería liberarse la memoria. Deberías estudiar el consumo de memoria en cada iteración, hay herramientas para ello.

Comment: Te refieres a  Java Visual Virtual Machine por ejemplo, o ¿que tipo de herramienta?

Comment: Como definitivamente no incluyes el código del método que está generando el problema, la respuesta que vas a obtener será muy amplia. Usa Java Flight Recorder para revisar qué está usando la memoria en tu aplicación mientras se ejecuta. Buena suerte

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo por tu recomendación , creo que he expuesto el problema de no poder insertar el código de ese método ya que es muy amplio y extenso utilizando diferentes clases implicadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si con el tiempo tu aplicación requiere cada vez más memoria, tienes lo que se llama un *memory leak* ([fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria)).

No es el número de variables, sino el tamaño en memoria de cada una: 100 valores `Integer` ocupan casi nada en comparación con una `List<Integer>` con 10000 elementos. Comprueba que no uses variables globales que guarden información innecesariamente (atributos de clase que sean `static`), por ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias Pablo por responder, efectivamente utilizo ArrayList<>, List<> y de forma static para utilizarlos en diferentes métodos de alguna clase interna.

Comment: ¿No se podría resolver, creando un hilo diferente?, digamos para cada vuelta.